# Change the tabhost style android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I want to change the default blue color of the tabhost to red.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
          <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@drawable/tab_indicator_holo</item>
          </style>
```

tab_indicator_holo.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

But the tab style is not applied to the tabhost. The default blue color is not changed to red.

I am getting this

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions please.

Comment: `android:tabWidgetStyle` should point to a style extending `Widget.TabWidget`(which in turn would override one of its tab strip attributes to point to the `tab_indicator_holo.xml` drawable that you have).

Answer (score 5):

You might have already found the answer, but for those who may face the same problem, Here is what I have done.

1. go to [custom holo theme](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and set tabwedget to yes and choose preferred color.
2. Download the zip, copy over to my project.
3. Add to tabadapter with the view created by inflating tab_indicator_holo.

```
    View mIndicator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_holo, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title1 = (TextView) mIndicator.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

    title1.setText("TAB1");

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1").setIndicator( mIndicator), FRAGMENT1.class, null);

    View mIndicator2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_holo,      mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title2 = (TextView) mIndicator2.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

    title2.setText("TAB2");
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TAB2").setIndicator(mIndicator2), FRAGMENT2.class, null);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is finally exactly what I needed. Awesome!

Comment: NyanLH, can you complete your code example? Which function to add this to? Where does inflater, mTabsAdapter come from?